# Implementing NSTableViewRowAction using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

This should be simple but I cannot understand how to implement this action.

I found this reference using objective-c but I want to do this using swift:

```
- (NSArray<NSTableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView rowActionsForRow:(NSInteger)row edge:(NSTableRowActionEdge)edge {
    NSTableViewRowAction *action = [NSTableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:NSTableViewRowActionStyleDestructive title:@"Delete"
        handler:^(NSTableViewRowAction * _Nonnull action, NSInteger row) {
        // TODO: You code to delete from your model here.
        NSLog(@"Delete");
    }];
    return @[action];
}
```

I understand I need to implement the function but do not know how to implement the method.
I am new to macOS development having developed two apps for iOS on the App Store I figured porting them to MacOS would be relatively simple, my mistake!!

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swipeable tables were added in macOS 10.11, so to access the functionality you'll need to implement this `NSTableViewDelegate` method on your table delegate. For example, adding an extension for your view controller would be as simple as:

```
extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableRowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
        // left swipe
        if edge == .trailing {
            let deleteAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
                // action code
            })

            deleteAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
            return [deleteAction]
        }

        let archiveAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "Archive", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
            // action code
        })

        return [archiveAction]
    }
}
```

Comment: I am feeling dumber by the minute because I cannot see where to say a huge thank you mfessenden, and this input field seems to say I shouldn't use it to say thank you, but, what the hell, thank you. I now need to figure out why I couldn't figure it out myself

Comment: You're very welcome. Feel free to mark the question 'answered' if it works for you :)