# Remove row from NSTableview by swiping

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview

I am trying to remove a row from my NStableView by swipe function. I am using macOS 10.13 and swift 4 and pretty new to swift coding.

I tried to follow: [Implementing NSTableViewRowAction using Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795726/implementing-nstableviewrowaction-using-swift) but it did not work for me.

And this is how I implement it:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableView.RowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
    // left swipe
    if edge == .trailing {
        let deleteAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
            // action code
            List_Symbol.remove(at: row)
            List_Price.remove(at: row)
            List_Procent.remove(at: row)
            List_Volume.remove(at: row)
        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        return [deleteAction]
    }
    let archiveAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "Archive", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
        // action code
    })
    return [archiveAction]
}
```

Any other suggestion how to delete row in NSTableView by swiping?

The Whole code:

```
import Cocoa
import Alamofire

var List_Symbol = ["AAPL"]
var List_Price  = [10.0]
var List_Procent = [1.0]
var List_Volume = [100]


class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource,     NSTableViewDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!
@IBOutlet weak var input: NSTextField!
@IBAction func additem(_ sender: Any) {
    if (input.stringValue != ""){
        var Stock = StockInformation(symbol: input.stringValue)
        Stock.GetStockInformation {
            List_Symbol.append(Stock.Symbol)
            List_Price.append(Stock.Price)
            List_Procent.append(Stock.Percent)
            List_Volume.append(Stock.Volume)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        input.stringValue = ""
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableView.RowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
    // left swipe
    if edge == .trailing {
        let deleteAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
            // action code
            List_Symbol.remove(at: row)
            List_Price.remove(at: row)
            List_Procent.remove(at: row)
            List_Volume.remove(at: row)
            tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: row), withAnimation: .effectFade)
        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        return [deleteAction]
    }
    let archiveAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .regular, title: "Archive", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
        // action code
    })
    return [archiveAction]
}



override func viewDidAppear() {
    tableView.reloadData()
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
 func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int{
    return List_Symbol.count
}

 func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any?{
    var identifierStr = tableColumn!.identifier
    if (identifierStr.rawValue == "StockNameCellID"){
        return List_Symbol[row]
    }else if (identifierStr.rawValue == "PriceCellID"){
        return List_Price[row]
    }else if (identifierStr.rawValue == "PercentCellID"){
        return List_Procent[row]
    }else if (identifierStr.rawValue == "VolumeCellID"){
        return List_Volume[row]
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
    return nil
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use multiple arrays as data source, that's horrible.

In macOS you can replace a lot of boilerplate code with Cocoa Bindings

• Use a class inherited from `NSObject` as data source

```
@objcMembers
class Stock : NSObject {
    dynamic var symbol : String
    dynamic var price : Double
    dynamic var procent : Double
    dynamic var volume : Int

    init(symbol : String, price : Double, procent : Double, volume : Int) {
        self.symbol = symbol
        self.price = price
        self.procent = procent
        self.volume = volume
    }
}
```

• Declare the data source array **within** the view controller

```
@objc var stocks = [Stock]()
```

• In `additem` create a new `Stock` item, rather then reloading the table view insert only the row with a smart animation

```
@IBAction func additem(_ sender: Any) {
    if !input.stringValue.isEmpty {
        let stock = StockInformation(symbol: input.stringValue)
        stock.GetStockInformation {
            let newStock = Stock(symbol: stock.Symbol, price: stock.Price, procent: stock.Percent, volume: stock.Volume)
            let insertionIndex = IndexSet(integer: stocks.count)
            self.stocks.append(newStock)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertionIndex, withAnimation: .effectGap)
            self.input.stringValue = ""
        }
    }
}
```

• `objectValueFor` and `numberOfRows` are only one line respectively

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int{
    return stocks.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    return stocks[row]
}
```

• The `delete` action is

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, rowActionsForRow row: Int, edge: NSTableView.RowActionEdge) -> [NSTableViewRowAction] {
    print("swipe")
    // left swipe
    if edge == .trailing {
        let deleteAction = NSTableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete", handler: { (rowAction, row) in
            // action code
            self.stocks.remove(at: row)
            tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: row), withAnimation: .effectFade)
        })
        deleteAction.backgroundColor = NSColor.red
        return [deleteAction]
    }
}
```

• In Interface Builder connect datasource and delegate of the table view to the view controller. Further press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> (Bindings Inspector), then select each `Table View Cell` (the `NSTextField` **not** `NSTextFieldCell` and **not** `Table Cell View`!) and bind the `Value` to `Table Cell View` and `Model Key Path` to the corresponding property (`objectValue.symbol`, `objectValue.price` etc.)

You can even use more `Cocoa Bindings` by binding the `content` of the table view to the `stocks` array. Then you can get rid of the datasource and its methods.

[image]

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out how to add text inside the table cell, not through the code. So I can always edit the text inside the "note" cell. Any suggestions? :-)

Comment: Make the cell view `editable` in Interface Builder. If `note` is bound to the property in the class all changes are synced.

Comment: can we add this delete funtionality to custom cell also ?

Comment: @TheiCoder I think so.

Comment: @vadian I have added the delegate method but its not called.

Comment: Is `delegate` connected?